# setInterval started with a button or started alone

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i active/fire/trigger the setInterval with a button? and if the button is not clicked how to make it auto fire on 3 second, but if i click on the button it fire it on 0.1
second and restart evrything. please help me out guys

```
$('button').click(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
    }, 100);
});  

else 

setInterval(function(){
    updateStats("updateStats");
}, 3000);
```

*Edit*

Only everytime the button is clicked 100ms, if not clicked then it most do it auto on 3000ms, unless you click it ofc

Part :

```
function updateStats(stat)
{



    var stat = ["GAME","USERS"];

    var url = "NET.php";

   $.each(stat, function(i, key){
       $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) { // stats to stat


          $("#" + key).html(data);  




                    $('.s').emoticonize({
                        //delay: 800,
                        //animate: false
                    });


       });


    });


}
```

Comment: Do you want it to fire **every** 100ms, or just once 100ms after button click?

Comment: Please be more specific. The logic of  "if button X is clicked to this else that" is a bit strange. Clicking a button is an action, not a state, so it does not really make sense in an if-else context.

Comment: Sorry, only everytime the button is clicked  100ms, if not clicked then it most do it auto on 3000ms, unless you click it ofc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fire after 3000 if you clicked the button it will fire after 100

```
var x ;

// call timer after 3000
callTimer(3000);

// call timer after 100 if cicked
$('button').click(function(){
     clearInterval(x);
     callTimer(100);
 });  


 function callTimer(time){
   x = setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
        }, time);
  }
```

**UPDATE** upon your request

```
var x ;
var y ;

// call timer after 3000
callTimer(3000);

// call timer after 100 if cicked
$('button').click(function(){
     y = setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
        clearInterval(y);
        }, 100);
    callTimer(3000);
});  

 function callTimer(time){
   clearInterval(x);
   x = setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
      }, time);
 }
```

Comment: Can you reset the 3000ms if the button is clicked?, i tried to click on the button it look like it wait longer

Comment: I tried it, but when i click.. it dos not work fast.. it act as if the click was 3000 ms

Comment: about your added code ... the post request you sent it may be consume a time so may be you feel it doesn't work fast

Comment: That true, how to not make it take that time

Comment: it must consume time even a little because it's a new request you send
the new request is like a journey to server side a return so it take a time

Comment: But when i change callTimer(3000); to 1000-2000 it feels like it act on this, becouse the speed change for both

Answer (score 1):

Save it in a global variable to clear the timeout reference on click:

```
var tid = setTimeout(function(){
    updateStats("updateStats");
}, 3000);

$('button').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(tid);
    setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: He said it should only fire once in the comments, so change the `setInterval` to `setTimeout` and you've got a +1 ;)

Comment: Right, It would be easier to follow if the OP edited the original question instead of adding another comment with important requirements...

Comment: I tried it, but it take longer for the button, more then 100 ms to know

Answer (score 1):

On page load call setInterval to fire after 3 seconds.

On button click, call the setInterval in 100 miliseconds, and clear the default interval.

```
$('button').click(function(){    
setInterval(function(){
  updateStats("updateStats");    
  clearInterval(defaultTimer);
}, 100);    
});      
var defaultTimer = setInterval(function(){
  updateStats("updateStats");
}, 3000);
```

If you don't want this to be repeated, use setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Comment: the button toke more then 100 ms

Comment: How much more? It shouldn't take longer. How do you measure it taking longer?

Comment: if you have firebug, try using console.log. It can give you some debug information.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inter = setInterval(function(){
    updateStats("updateStats");
}, 3000);

$('button').mousedown(function() {
    clearInterval(inter);
    inter = setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
    }, 100);
});
$('button').mouseup(function() {
      clearInterval(inter);
      inter = setInterval(function(){
        updateStats("updateStats");
    }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: I was clicking on the button, but it took more then 100 ms

Comment: @user1417815 because you're using `(ajax)  $.post` you can not force it load in 100 ms

Comment: @user1417815 there is no trick, you have to wait until ajax request ends

Comment: @David see updated question he's using `$.post` inside `updateStats()`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var interval;
 $(document).ready(function(){
 interval = setInterval(function(){
updateStats("updateStats");
}, 3000);

});
```

`$('button').click(function(){`
   `clearInterval(interval);`
   `setInterval(function(){`
   `updateStats("updateStats");`
   `}, 100);});`